# Not able to store data scraped with scrapy in json or csv format

Tags: json, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

Here I want to store the data from the list given on a website page. If I'm running the commands

```
response.css('title::text').extract_first()        and
response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()
```

individually in the scrapy shell it is showing expected output in shell.
Below is my code which is not storing data in json or csv format:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medical"

    start_urls = ['https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000178.html/']


    def parse(self, response):
        yield
        {
            'topic': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
            'symptoms': response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()
        }
```

I have tried to run this code using

```
scrapy crawl medical -o medical.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your URL, it is `https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000178.htm` and not `https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000178.html/`.

Also, and more importantly, you need to define an `Item` class and yield/return it from the `parse()` callback of your spider:

```
import scrapy


class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    topic = scrapy.Field()
    symptoms = scrapy.Field()


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medical"

    allowed_domains = ['medlineplus.gov']
    start_urls = ['https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000178.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()

        item["topic"] = response.css('title::text').extract_first()
        item["symptoms"] = response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()

        yield item
```